# Node.js event when Facebook page posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I'm using Node.js to build a site which involves getting posts from a public Facebook page.

I currently have the server updating my sqlite3 database from Facebook every n hours which works fine but I was wondering if there is some way I can set up an event which calls the update function whenever the page makes a post?

This would mean the site was always up to date with the page and there wouldn't be the delay of waiting until the next update time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Webhooks: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

...those can only be used if you manage the Page though, there is no way to subscribe to changes to a Page you don't own.